# pulling up matching rows from a matrix using dplyr

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

Suppose I have the following:

```
myDF <- cbind.data.frame("Id" = rep(1:5, each = 4), values = c(rnorm(4,0,1), rnorm(4, 10, 1), rnorm(4, 20,1 ), rnorm(4, 30,1), rnorm(4, 40,1)))

idVector <- sample(1:5, size =  5, replace = TRUE)
```

If my `idVector = 4,4,3,2,1', I want to pull all the rows with Id 4, then Id 4 again, then 3 then 2 then 1.

I can do it using the following:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(idVector, function(x, currentDF){
currentDF[currentDF$Id == x,]}
, myDF))
```

Is there a neater way to do it using dplyr or plyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(data.frame(Id=idVector), myDF)
```